# Copy As Latex automatically alphabetizes words

Tags: latex

If you take the following line, right click on it and `Copy As Latex`:

```
Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"what", " ", "are", " ", "you", "  ", "mode", " ", 
 Cell["f(x)", "Title"]}]], "Text",
  CellChangeTimes->{{3.578697794669105*^9, 3.5786978134524927`*^9}}]
```

The result of pasting that is:

```
\text{are}\text{mode}\text{what}\text{you}\text{f(x)}
```

which is an alphabetization of the original set of words. How is it possible to copy the original text into $\LaTeX$ while preserving the ordering.

Sometimes this kind of disorder occurs in converting to `TraditionalForm`.

```
ExportString[
Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"what"," ","are"," ","you","  ","mode"," ",
 Cell["f(x)","Title"]}]], "Text",
   CellChangeTimes->{{3.578697794669105*^9,3.5786978134524927`*^9}}],"Tex"]
```

it's ok.

how to add an item named `ExportLatexToString` below `Copy As Latex` in the menu comes via right click whose function is what `ExportString` done here, i.e. without the disorder of words?

My system is Windows-8 X64, Mathematica 9.0.1

Updating1:

I found `TextCell` and `TextData` should have not such disorders, maybe this is one of the right track, but the problem is how to convert default text-style-cell to `TextCell` like this one

```
CellPrint[TextCell[Row[{Style["bold", FontWeight->Bold], " are"}],"Text"]]
```

Comment: When I run the top line, I get "what are you mode" followed by a big red f(x).

Comment: The top line also appears to be correct for me. MMA version 9.0.0.0, Mac OS X Mountain Line on a Macbook Pro. @HyperGroups. Can you specify what system you are using?

Comment: @bill s windows x64 with Mathematica Version 9.0.1 I wonder if I mis-setting something...

Comment: @JonathanShock windows x64 with Mathematica Version 9.0.1.

Comment: I'm on mac os 10.6, mathematica 9.01. It looks like what's happening is that it is alphabetizing the words for you, as if they were being treated as variables.

Comment: I've edited the first half of the question as I now see that I get the same thing happening. This had not been clear from the original wording. I'm afraid I can't quite understand the second part however.

Comment: This is interpreted as a list of symbols which are being multiplied together. The issue is one of reordering of symbols within the `Times` command. This is because `Times` has attribute `Orderless`.

Comment: @JonathanShock en, I've added one picture show the error and my enviroment

Comment: @HyperGroups. I removed the picture originally as I thought that an explanation was actually clearer than the picture. You can write the environment into the question without including a picture.

Comment: @JonathanShock ok, Let me remove it.

Comment: @JonathanShock seems TextCell and TextData like this one with no such disorder. CellPrint[TextCell[Row[{Style["bold", FontWeight->Bold], " are"}],"Text"]]

Comment: @bills one update.

Comment: I'm sorry HyperGroups, I've lost track of what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to get an answer on record so the question can be removed from not-answered list.

Jonathan Shock answered the question in a comment:

> This is interpreted as a list of symbols which are being multiplied together. The issue is one of reordering of symbols within the `Times` command. This is because `Times` has attribute `Orderless`.